# Creating a CA certificate (.pem) file to connect to crate database

Tags: python, ssl, crate

I am trying to connect to a crate database with python

```
from crate import client
url = '434.342.435.2:4400' # Faked these numbers for purposes of this post
conn = client.connect(url)
```

It seems like I need to pass the `cert_file` and `key_file` arguments to `client.connect` which point to my `.pem` and `.key` files. Looking in [the documentation](https://crate.io/docs/reference/python/https.html), I cannot find any resource to create or download these files.

Any advice? Even a comment pointing me to a good resource for beginners would be appreciated.

Comment: If its your own development setup, you could probably use a self-signed certificate , instructions to generate one are here - http://serverfault.com/questions/224122/what-is-crt-and-key-and-how-can-i-generate-them , else you probably need to reach out to sys admins in your organisation for this info

Comment: The `cert_file` and `key_file` is optional and only needs to be provided if you're connecting to a Crate cluster that uses `https`.

Comment: @mfussenegger when I connect in my browser I am prompted for a username and password. Does this imply I am connecting via `https`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So cert and key files are part of the TLS encryption of a HTTP(S) connection that are required if you use a self-signed certificate :)

[This seems to be a very good explanation of the file types](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file)

As [mfussenegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333061/mfussenegger) explained in the comment, these files are optional and only required if your CrateDB instance is "hidden" behind a reverse proxy server like NGINX or Apache with a self-signed certificate. 
A small green lock on the far left of your browser's address bar indicates HTTPS (and therefore TLS) with known certificates. 
[image: valid certificate]

Typically certificates signed by an unknown CA - like yourself - result in a warning page and a red indicator:

[image: invalid certificate]

Since you are also referring to username and password, they usually indicate some sort of auth (maybe [basic auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)) which is not yet supported by crate-python :(

Comment: Thank you. I think you hit the nail on the head (for me) with that last line.